# RSA Asymmetric encryption / decryption - Which key is being used

Tags: encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

When I create a public/private key using the following code :

```
    // Create the CspParameters object and set the key container   
    // name used to store the RSA key pair.  
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
    cp.KeyContainerName = ContainerName;

    // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider that accesses  
    // the key container MyKeyContainerName.  
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
```

If I then call

```
    rsa.Encrypt (....
    OR
    rsa.Decrypt(..
```

how do I know which key is being used.  Whether the public or private key is used in each case is dependent on the application.  How can I determine which is being used ?

Comment: "Whether the public or private key is used in each case is dependent on the application. " - No.  That's wrong.  RSA encryption is only possible with the public key, decryption with the private key.

Comment: @MartinBonner - signing works the other way around. SignData() encrypts the hash with the private key.

Comment: Thanks that is perfect, and what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Henk Kinda.  In general, it is a mistake to consider "signing" as "encryption with the public key" (although the numerical operations are the same with RSA).

Comment: Then why would it be a mistake to consider it that way? (And you've got a public/private typo).

Answer (score 1):

**Encrypt** is done with the **public key**, and **decrypt** is done with the **private key** .. thus only the holder of the **private key** can **decrypt.**

You are not meant to decrypt using a public key, and thus the interface don't provide you with a way to do this.

Signatures utilizes encrypting using the private key, and decryption using the public key + some one way hash logic, but in this case the interface only allows this using specific signature methods (`SignData(..)` & `VerifyData(..)`).

Comment: You might want to flag the sentence where the OP says "Whether the public or private key is used in each case is dependent on the application." and point out that it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks that is perfect, and what I was hoping for.